# How to add alias to fish config?

Tags: fish

I read an article suggesting adding this to `~/.bashrc`

```
. ~/._awsAliases
alias awsall="_awsListAll"
alias awsp="_awsSwitchProfile"
alias awswho="aws configure list"
```

Since I am trying out fish shell I tried entering the same into `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

I get the error message:

```
~/._awsAliases (line 15): Missing end to balance this function definition
function _awsSwitchProfile() {
^
from sourcing file ~/._awsAliases
    called on line 185 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.1.2/share/fish/config.fish
in function '.' with arguments '/Users/_/._awsAliases'
    called on line 1 of file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
source: Error while reading file '/Users/_/._awsAliases'
```

How can I rewrite that configuration to be fish legal?

Answer (score 0):

Bash is a, more or less, POSIX compatible shell. Fish is not. The two shells have different syntax and behavior. So when you tell fish to parse POSIX syntax fish complains that it doesn't recognize that syntax.

You'll have to rewrite the content of *~/._awsAliases* to be compatible with fish. Since you didn't show us the content of that file there's no way for us to know if that rewrite is trivial or hard.

Comment: I didn't include it because that script started with a bash shebang. I thought that fish would execute those functions in bash. Is that not the case?

Comment: @user1283776, The dot (or `source`) command in fish and bash read the file and attempt to compile and execute the statements it contains. Neither shell pays any attention to the shebang line when sourcing a file. Furthermore, even if they did honor the shebang line it wouldn't do you any good since the functions the script defines would not be available in the shell running the `source` (or dot) command.